# How to query task with iteration equals to 'Current Iteration'

Tags: ado

In ADO, how to query task with iteration equals to 'Current Iteration'?

I tried:
[image]

But I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also add team in your query:[image]
Here is the document about [Team's current iteration queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#teams-current-iteration-queries) and you can refer to it.